# VueJS with 3rd Party Web API Token Management

Tags: vue.js, asp.net-web-api

I am developing a VueJS SPA which need to interact with 3rd Party Web API by passing credentials (Provided by 3rd party) and get a token from Web API. I will be using token for further requests to 3rd Party API. Is it a good practice to put credentials in .env file with in VueJS app and pass to Web API to get a token and use for further calls OR Do we need to have a Proxy Middleware for getting the Authentication Token, where we can pass credentials securely to 3rd Party API?

Answer (score 1):

using a proxy (even extremely rudimentary) is a good practice and a better alternative than making "plain" HTTP calls to third-party endpoints because it hides the secrets for the calls.

however, consider that the problem could still remain (even if marginal) as a malicious person could instead of stealing the endpoint's credentials, use the proxy directly to make calls at will.

to address this problem as well, it would be best to add an authentication layer to the proxy

Comment: Thanks Cosimo. Can you share any dotnet core samples available for Proxy server?

Comment: there are a thousand alternatives, it depends a little on where you want to host it and in what language to implement it

Comment: I will be using C# and asp.net and hosting it on IIS on a VM within the cloud.

Comment: I have often used ocelot, always found extremely good, easy to get started and full of features for the long term. https://github.com/ThreeMammals/Ocelot

Comment: Thanks Cosimo. I have used Ocelot and configured to make the calls to downstream server. The 3rd party API provides a token by calling a Post method with credentials. May I know where can I embed code to call 3rd party API and get token and include in Downstream url.